# About "Went on to do"

Tags: meaning

> After Jane quit her job as a receptionist, she went on to earn her
>   college degree

What does this sentence mean?

1. After Jane quit her job as a receptionist, she earned her college degree.
2. After Jane quit her job as a receptionist, she went on in order to earn her college degree. (We don't know whether Jane earned the college degree or not)
3. Either 1 or 2 according to context.

To me, the sentence sounds very ambiguous, so I would choose 3 because there is no clue that Jane really earned her college degree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The answer is 1**
She did not try to earn her degree, she earned it according to the information available.''

**earn** means to **receive** or to get something that you deserve because of your abilities or actions:[Link to C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/earn)

Answer (score 0):

"Went on" means "to engage is some activity or task" according to Dictionary.com as seen [here](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/went+on).

Sentence one is correct. It means:

> After Jane quit her job, she continued being active and she earned her
>   college degree.